# Printing out Deck of Cards

Tags: javascript, object

Trying to figure out what I am missing here! The cards create, I can print out the object and it's contents using the `document.write(JSON.stringify());` at the bottom. The 'main' method at the bottom is me trying to call cardToString, which should take the contents of the object, and return a string which is then outputted. Can't seem to figure out what I am missing here.

```
(function () {

function Card (rank, suit) {

    this.rank = rank;
    this.suit = suit;

};

function Deck() {

    this.deck = new Array();

    this.makeDeck = makeDeck;
    this.shuffle = shuffle;
    this.deal = deal;
}
function makeDeck() {

    var ranks = new Array("A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
                    "J", "Q", "K");
    var suits = new Array("C", "D", "H", "S");

    this.deck = new Array(52);

    var i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
            this.deck[i*ranks.length + j] = new Card(ranks[j], suits[i]);
        }
    }
};

function shuffle() {
    var i, j, temp;
    var n = 10;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < this.deck.length; j++) {
            k = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.deck.length);
            temp = this.deck[j];
            this.deck[j] = this.deck[k];
            this.deck[k] = temp;
        }
    }
};

function deal() {

    if (this.deck.length > 0) {

        return this.deck.shift();
    }
    else return null;
};

function cardToString(rank, suit) {

   document.write(rank + suit + " ");
   var strRank, strSuit;

   strRank = String(rank);
   strSuit = String(suit);

   var theRank, theSuit;

    switch (strRank) {
      case "A" :
        theRank = "Ace";
        break;
      case "2" :
        theRank = "Two";
        break;
      case "3" :
        theRank = "Three";
        break;
      case "4" :
        theRank = "Four";
        break;
      case "5" :
        theRank = "Five";
        break;
      case "6" :
        theRank = "Six";
        break;
      case "7" :
        theRank = "Seven";
        break;
      case "8" :
        theRank = "Eight";
        break;
      case "9" :
        theRank = "Nine";
        break;
      case "10" :
        theRank = "Ten";
        break;
      case "J" :
        theRank = "Jack";
        break;
      case "Q" :
        theRank = "Queen";
        break;
      case "K" :
        theRank = "King";
        break;
      default :
        theRank = null;
        break;
    }

    switch (strSuit) {
      case "C" :
        theSuit = "Clubs";
        break;
      case "D" :
        theSuit = "Diamonds";
        break;
      case "H" :
        theSuit = "Hearts";
        break;
      case "S" :
        theSuit = "Spades";
        break;
      default :
        theSuit = null;
        break;
    }

    if (rank == null || suit == null) {
      return "";
    }

    return this.rank + " of " + this.suit;
}

var deck = new Deck();

deck.makeDeck();
deck.shuffle();
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        var Card;
        Card = deck.deal();
        //document.write(Card.rank);
        var v = cardToString(Card.rank, Card.suit);
        document.write(v);
    }
}


    } ());
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get values out of the card object you'll need to pass it as an argument to `cardToString()`. Since your object name is `Card` it would be written as `cardToString(Card)`.

To pull the values from the card object you'll want to modify the `cardToString` function a bit. Instead of using `this` you'll use the object passed named `card`. I've updated the function below to give you and idea of how this might work.

```
function cardToString(card) {

    var rank, suit;

    switch (card.rank) {
      case "A" :
        rank = "Ace";
        break;
      case "2" :
        rank = "Two";
        break;
      case "3" :
        rank = "Three";
        break;
      case "4" :
        rank = "Four";
        break;
      case "5" :
        rank = "Five";
        break;
      case "6" :
        rank = "Six";
        break;
      case "7" :
        rank = "Seven";
        break;
      case "8" :
        rank = "Eight";
        break;
      case "9" :
        rank = "Nine";
        break;
      case "10" :
        rank = "Ten";
        break;
      case "J" :
        rank = "Jack";
        break;
      case "Q" :
        rank = "Queen";
        break;
      case "K" :
        rank = "King";
        break;
      default :
        rank = null;
        break;
    }

    switch (card.suit) {
      case "C" :
        suit = "Clubs";
        break;
      case "D" :
        suit = "Diamonds";
        break;
      case "H" :
        suit = "Hearts";
        break;
      case "S" :
        suit = "Spades";
        break;
      default :
        suit = null;
        break;
    }

    if (rank == null || suit == null) {
      return "";
    }

    return rank + " of " + suit;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work. I made some changes to my code above which got my through, but it didn't seem to pickup any the cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to finish you function for cardToString. You need to make rank, suit as input, and pass them in like var v = cardToString(Card.rank, Card.suit);

Comment: that was dumb of me...thanks. I have since fixed that, passes fine, however I seem to get a bunch of returns like this `undefined of undefined`. I tried parsing the objects to Strings, but that made no difference. I updated the code above.

Comment: You need to return theSuit and theSuit, instead of rank and suit. don't use "this." and make sure you declare  theSuit and theSuit too.